# Solve with Simplify yields Real Solution and Solve with FullSimplify a Complex Solution?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a problem with the DSolve[] command in mathematica 8. Solving the the following 4th order differential equation spits out a complex solution although it should be a real one.
The equation is:

```
y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0
```

Solving this equation by hand yields a solution with only real parts. All constants and boundary conditions are also real numbers.

The solution I get by hand is:

```
y1[x_] = (C[5] E^(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1] x) + 
  C[6] E^(-(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1]) x)) Cos[
 Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1]
   x] + (C[7] E^(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1] x) + 
  C[8] E^(-(Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1]) x)) Sin[
 Power[a, (4)^-1]/Power[2, (2)^-1] x];
```

Now I have to solve for the constants C[5]...C[8]. This arises a similar issue. I use the Solve[] command with the boundary conditions

```
Solve[{y1''[-c] == ic0, y1''[c] == ic0 , y1'''[-c] == ic1 , 
y1'''[c] == - ic1 }, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]} ];
```

The constants C[5]...C[8] are now real if using //Simplify and complex if using //FullSimplify.

Any idea what the reasons are?
The notebook with my calculations can be downloaded under:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4920002/DGL_4th_Order_with_own_solution.nb

In further work I have to use DSolve[] and I would like to understand the issue here.

Thanks,

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I think that some of your statements depend on the details. For instance some of the parameters `C[]` can be complex numbers if you choose `a<0` :

```
parS = Solve[{y1''[-c] == ic0, y1''[c] == ic0, y1'''[-c] == ic1, 
    y1'''[c] == -ic1}, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]}] // Simplify;
parFS = Solve[{y1''[-c] == ic0, y1''[c] == ic0, y1'''[-c] == ic1, 
    y1'''[c] == -ic1}, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]}] // FullSimplify

parS /. {a -> -2, c -> 10, ic0 -> 1, ic1 -> -1} // N
parFS /. {a -> -2, c -> 10, ic0 -> 1, ic1 -> -1} // N

(* {{C[5] -> -0.35876 - 2.498*10^-15 I,  C[6] -> -0.35876 - 2.498*10^-15 I, 
     C[7] -> 2.27596*10^-15 - 0.358762 I, C[8] -> -2.27596*10^-15 + 0.358762 I}}

   {{C[5] -> -0.35876 + 5.10703*10^-15 I, C[6] -> -0.35876 + 5.10703*10^-15 I, 
     C[7] -> 2.35922*10^-15 - 0.358762 I, C[8] -> -2.19269*10^-15 + 0.358762 I}} *)
```

Besides this point you can get the solution to your problem in one line and indeed it seems a real function (apart from numerics) :

```
sol[a_, ic0_, ic1_, c_, x_] = y[x] /. DSolve[{y''''[x] + a y[x] == 0, y''[-c] == ic0, 
     y''[c] == ic0, y'''[-c] == ic1, y'''[c] == -ic1}, y[x], x][[1]] ;

Plot[Im[sol[-2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 10., x]], {x, -10., 10.}]
Plot[Re[sol[-2.0, 1.0, -1.0, 10., x]], {x, -10., 10.}]
```

[image: Im]
[image: Re]

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.
I forgot to give the download link for my notebook. it can be downloaded under:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4920002/DGL_4th_Order_with_own_solution.nb

I also get this behaviour in the symbolic calculation (in the notebook y3[x] is Real and y4[x] is complex). 

Also for a>0 I get complex constants

Answer (score 0):

Since you cross-posted the question to [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10253/dsolve-gives-complex-function-although-the-solution-is-a-real-one), I gave an answer there. The crux of it is that even with a real and positive value for `a`, **the general solution to your fourth-order differential equation is complex**. Period. If you happen to be only interested in the real solutions, [it is possible to extract them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10253/dsolve-gives-complex-function-although-the-solution-is-a-real-one).